# CMMotionManager and the Gyroscope on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to simply NSLog the output of the new iPhone 4 Gyroscope. But after reading the documentation and following their sample code I am getting this error.

```
ERROR,Time,300635803.946,Function,"CLLoggingSetFile",could not open locations log /var/mobile/Library/Caches/CoreMotion/CoreMotion.log
```

Even if I just setup my motionManager object with [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; on its own and no other code, I still get the error.

Here is my .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface GyroTest0ViewController : UIViewController {
    CMMotionManager *motionManager;
    NSOperationQueue *opQ;
}

@end
```

And here my .m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // the error occurs even just with this line on its own
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; 

    if (motionManager.gyroAvailable) {
        motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
        [motionManager startGyroUpdates];
        opQ = [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] retain];
        CMGyroHandler gyroHandler = ^ (CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
            CMRotationRate rotate = gyroData.rotationRate;
            NSLog(@"rotation rate = [%f, %f, %f]", rotate.x, rotate.y, rotate.z);
        };
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No gyroscope on device.");
        [motionManager release];
    }
}
```

Any help and/or source code to simply log the iPhone 4 gyroscope data would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Its a bug that has no affect on the running of the application.

Comment: After iOS 4.2 is out the error message disappeared. I think we can close this.

Comment: I get the same error when I try to log the 'attitude', but the error does not seem to cause a real problem: the NSLog works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any results regarding this issue? I get the same error even when I use WWDC teapot demo code.
I filed a bug report (8382659).

By the way I get the same error when I use the push method described by Joshua Weinberg.

Update: Apple confirmed the bug but referred to a duplicate issue 8173937 that I can't find. Well let's hope that it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: After iOS 4.2 is out the error message disappeared. I think we can close this. (Kay).

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
    [motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                               withHandler: ^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error)
                                            {
                                                CMRotationRate rotate = gyroData.rotationRate;
                                                NSLog(@"rotation rate = [%f, %f, %f]", rotate.x, rotate.y, rotate.z);
                                            }];
```

Answer (score 3):

For the WWDC sample code:

- Log in to ADC
- Click on WWDC 2010 session videos
- View in iTunes
- There you find the link to sample code (230 MB)

Comment: Here's a link to the 2010 WWDC sample code: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645