# IOS Accelerometer/Gyroscope Question

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope

I want to write an app that gives the degrees of position from some coordinate (bottom of the phone).

For example... If I'm holding the phone at a 45 degree angle, I want to display: 45 degrees on the screen. If the user holds the phone at 45 degrees and rotates the phone around an axis going from the ear piece to the home button, I want to display that angle (between 0-180degrees).

I've implemented the accelerometer and I get the x, y, z values, however, how do I convert them? I know they are in G's (1G, 0.9G, -0.5G on the respective axis), but what's the conversion? Am I even going on the correct track? Should I be using the gyroscope instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262586/get-device-plane-relative-to-ground-plane-using-accelerometer) has an example. You can use `atan2(y, x)` and convert from radians to degrees with `* (180/M_PI)`.

> For any real arguments x and y not both equal to zero, atan2(y, x) is the angle in radians between the positive x-axis of a plane and the point given by the coordinates (x, y) on it.

- Wikipedia article on [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on gyroscope support I'd recommend to use it, because you can get the (Euler) angles directly without any calculations. See [iOS - gyroscope sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237763/ios-gyroscope-sample/7241478#7241478) and follow the links inside.

Don't use UIAccelerometer because it will be deprecated soon. The newer CoreMotion framework is always the better choice, even for old devices.